# override method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, overriding

If I want to override the following method:

```
public Machine makeMachine(String machineName, int machineSize)
{
  return new Machine(machineName, machineSize);
}
```

With:

```
public Machine makeDramaticMachine(String machineName, int machineSize)
{
  return new DramaticMachine(machineName, machineSize);
}
```

Would this be correct?

Comment: so would the signature remain like this:                                                           public Machine makeMachine(String machineName, int machineSize)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it would not be since you've changed the method "signature". the method name and its parameter list must be unchanged for this to be a true override. Always use the @Override annotation to test if your overrides are true overrides. e.g.:

```
@Override // always use this annotation just to be sure
public Foo myMethod(Bar baz) {
   // ... code in here
}
```

By using the annotation, you will force the compiler to check if the override is true or not before you run your code.

Answer (score 5):

No by definition. 
Overriding method means implementing method with the same signature in sub class. Your method has different name, so it cannot override the first method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override by changing the name.